# How do I modify permissions settings for a specific website in Android Firefox?

Tags: android, firefox

It apparently used to work to press and hold the address bar but it doesn't any more. Neither can I find anything in settings. I denied access to the camera, and ticked "Don't ask me again" and would like to know how to reverse it. I know I could probably clear all data for the app, or reinstall, but I need to know how to instruct other users to do this, without them losing all their browser history etc.

Comment: Are you talking about the Android's permission dialog? You have denied camera permission with *don't ask again* and now don't know how to undo that?

Comment: It is Firefox's permission dialog. Other browsers like Chrome and Safari allow you to get into any site's settings and revoke permissions settings you've previously made

Comment: so you are basically asking us how to use firefox? How does your question relate to software development?

Comment: Because I'm developing a web app that behaves differently when the camera is called on the 3 major browsers, and I need to understand as a software developers how to instruct my users to deal with all sorts of combinations and possibilities of their current browser settings.